# How to include meta data in HTML tags

Tags: html, meta-tags

I plan to use a headless-CMS to manage content on my website, so a non-technical content editor will be able to independently maintain content.

To assist the content editor map content between the website and the CMS, I need to inject a CMS ID into HTML tags. (thinking that the content editor will view the page source to find the value)

What is the standard way to inject meta data into a HTML tag?

E.g. `<p cms-id=7adQpNPZxP4jK28RLp3wES></p>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use data attributes on elements - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes.

It doesn't interfere with HTML semantics and is easily accessible with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The `<meta>` tag defines metadata about an HTML document. Metadata is information about data.

`<meta>` tags always go inside the `<head>` element, and are typically used to specify character set, page description, keywords, author of the document, and viewport settings.

Comment: Yep. But the <meta> tag doesn't help me identify multiple elements on the same page.